# why not java support bytecodes that directly put operand into local variable table?

Tags: java, bytecode

for example, such code snippet `int a=6` would be compiled as:

```
bipush 6 //push into stack
astore_1 //pop
```

why not just support such bytecodes as:

```
astore_1 6 //directy put into local variable table
```

the latter one has less operations compared with the former, which will execute faster.

Comment: You mean `bipush 6; istore_1;`

Comment: @Holger yes, I've modified the question

Comment: Your are still using `astore` instead of `istore`.

Answer (score 1):

The JVM optimizes bytecode at runtime, so the second example is unlikely to actually be faster. Furthermore, there are advantages to having the compiler be simple. Therefore, the Java compiler does very little optimization and relies on the JVM to optimize everything at runtime.